# how can i adjust space between elements of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, spacing

I want such type of output

```
    [[ 1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  1.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

But I am getting This

```
    [[1. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 0.]
     [0. 0. 1.]]
```

My code is this :

```
import numpy
print(numpy.identity(size))
```

Comment: There are controls in `np.set_print_options`.  But if you are a `numpy` beginner, I'd suggest focusing your learning elsewhere.

Comment: https://thispointer.com/numpy-arange-create-a-numpy-array-of-evenly-spaced-numbers-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={'all': lambda x: " {:.0f} ".format(x)})
```

If you want to add the decimal point replace " {:.0f} " by " {:.0f}. "

You can modify the number of spaces or formatting in general in the lambda function.

Comment: actually it's adjusting spacing between the elements but it converts 1. to 1.0 and 0. to 0.0 which i don't want.

Comment: @Nitish770 I edited the post, depending wether you need the decimal point or not.

Answer (score 0):

use **numpy.arrange(start, stop, size)**
as follow

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1,   2,   3,   4,   5], [6,  7,  8,  9,  0]])

arr2 = np.arange(1, 9, 1)

print(arr2)
```

output

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Comment: I don't think he's interested in the numeric space, but rather the print display of a 2d array.